# Changing the scope of the object

Tags: websphere

Is it possible to change the scope of the existing object (such as JDBCProvider) on Websphere (more specifically, version 8.5)?

I can't find that option in the Admin Console neither find information how to do it with scripting, but it should be possible? It's less invasive operation than deleting the object and re-creating it in other scope.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't a way do "change" the scope of an object.

With Jython script, I'm sure there's a way to go and get whatever object you want, re-create it in the scope you want, then delete the original object.  That's probably your best option at this point...